# How can I pull opsworks variables into a .env file with chef?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, laravel-5, aws-opsworks

I am very new to chef and am on the last piece of the puzzle.  I am trying to create a .env file in my project root using variables set in AWS Opsworks.  I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Does anyone have any suggestions or a working chef recipe for this? I've googled to my wits end.

Comment: You can reference environment variables in .env configurations. Check out this quick guide:
https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-forge-using-environment-variables-for-environment-detection

Comment: I may be missing it but where does this blog post talk about getting variables set in opsworks into a .env file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't usually use a `.env` file if you're using AWS*. The .env file mimics environment variables which are actually set at an operating system level, this is useful for when you're developing locally or you're on a hosting platform which doesn't allow you to set these yourself.

So, all you need to do is set the environment variables for your app in Opsworks and you're done. These will be loaded from the operating system by PHP and are then available to your Laravel application.

*The reason for this is you usually have sensitive data such as database and API credentials stored in here. You absolutely want to keep these separate from your code and out of source control.

**Edit:**

You can write a .env file during deployment a bit like this if you need. This would be what your Chef script would look like:

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
  # write out .env file
  template "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/.env" do
    source 'env.erb'
    mode '0660'
    owner deploy[:user]
    group deploy[:group]
    variables(
      :env => deploy[:environment_variables]
    )
  end
end
```

This is what your .env file template would look like:

```
<% @env.each do |key, value| %>
<%= key %>=<%= value %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have them in there but they aren't working. I didn't use the Php built into opsworks I had to use a custom one because of nginx. The supplied Php deployment uses Apache.  So I set them and the code is written to use them in Laravel but it doesn't.

Comment: wow thank you, this is great. Do you buy any chance know if it's possible to run something only once? like a migration? i know its off topic

Comment: Laravel migrations will only run once out the box - it makes a database table called `migrations` and keeps track of what's been run and what hasn't.